# select dependent on counting two columns

Tags: mysql

I have this kind of table selected from database:

```
user project role 
XXX  p1      admin 
XXX  p2      developer 
xxx  p1      developer 
yyy  p3      tester 
yyy  p1      developer 
yyy  p1      admin 
zzz  p2      developer
```

and I need to add to this query filter: if user has at lease two roles in one project.

How can I do that? What MySQL functions can help me in this case?

Comment: Have you tried searching for MySql functions?

Comment: Are you expecting to get 2 users?  xxx and yyy?  Or will you be providing a user and expecting a true/false answer?

Comment: SELECT  DISTINCT user
        FROM  
        (
            SELECT  user, project, COUNT(\*) AS ct
                FROM  tbl
                GROUP BY  user, project
                HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 2 
        ) AS s

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` project and add an `HAVING` clause to restrict to those with `COUNT` > 1

```
SELECT user, project, count(*) AS number_of_roles
FROM thetable
GROUP BY project
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Bonus: a column with all roles aggregated

```
SELECT user, project, count(*) AS number_of_roles, GROUP_CONCAT(role) AS roles  
FROM thetable
GROUP BY project
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Not good form to `GROUP BY` one column (project), but have another non-aggregated (user)